# How to run unit tests with all Android M permissions granted?

Tags: android, unit-testing, robotium

Is there a gradle plugin that allows adb commandline options when installing android apps? I'm looking to run robotium tests on an Android M device, while ignoring the permission dialogs that pop up that ask for camera, microphone, etc, permissions.

Answer (score 9):

in build.gradle

```
task grantPermissions(type: Exec, dependsOn: 'installDebugAndroidTest') {
def permissions = ['INTERNET',
                   'GET_ACCOUNTS',
                   'WAKE_LOCK',
                   'VIBRATE',
                   'READ_CONTACTS',
                   'RECORD_AUDIO',
                   'CAMERA',
                   'WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE',
                   'READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE']
permissions.each {
    commandLine "\$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb shell pm grant com.singlewire.cirrus android.permission.${it}".split(' ')
}}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name.startsWith('connectedDebugAndroidTest')) {
       task.dependsOn grantPermissions
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
android.productFlavors.all { flavour ->
def applicationId = flavour.applicationId
def adb = android.getAdbExe().toString()

def grantPermissionsTask = tasks.create("grant${flavour.name.capitalize()}Permissions") << {
    "${adb} shell pm grant ${applicationId} android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION".execute()
    "${adb} shell pm grant ${applicationId} android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION".execute()
}
grantPermissionsTask.description = "Grants permissions for Marshmallow"

tasks.whenTaskAdded { theTask ->
    def assemblePattern = ~"assemble${flavour.name.capitalize()}DebugAndroidTest"
    if (assemblePattern.matcher(theTask.name).matches()) {
        theTask.dependsOn grantPermissionsTask.name
    }
}
}
```

You can do it for **instrumentation testing** only not for unit testing.
[Reference](https://afterecho.uk/blog/granting-marshmallow-permissions-for-testing-flavoured-builds.html)